# How do I pass an array into this function and call the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How do I pass an array into this function and call the function?

```
function whosPaying(names){

var noOfPeople = names.length;

var randomPersonPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * noOfPeople);

var randomPerson = names[randomPersonPosition];

return randomPerson + " is going to buy lunch today!";

}
```

I'm using JavaScript console in Chrome.

When I click run and go into my console, I have no idea how to test if this works. I just keep getting errors, no matter what I try. I've googled, gone through the other questions, and come up with nothing. Can anyone please help? I realize the solution is probably pretty simple, so please forgive my naivety.

Comment: _"When I click run and go into my console..."_ - What _"run"_? And why would you call it manually in the console? Just add a `whosPaying(["Rachel", "John", "Mickey"])` in your editor and call it.

Comment: `noOfPeople` is a typo or `noOfpeople` is. Notice the `p` and `P`?

Comment: Thanks, I changed that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in chrome console you can call like this. FYI there is a typo in your code for variable noOfPeople at line:3

```js
console.log(function whosPaying(names){

var noOfPeople = names.length;

var randomPersonPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * noOfPeople);

var randomPerson = names[randomPersonPosition];

return randomPerson + " is going to buy lunch today!";

}(["name1", "name2","name3", "name4"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll call it like any other function.
First declare it as you've already done.
Then call it like

```
whosPaying(["xyz", "qwe", "abc"])
```

Comment: The question is, "how to pass an array and call the function". So, this is the solution.